# How to check in AngularJs if some dates are greater then others

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to check if some date fields are greater then others.
I solved in this way for only one couple of dates. I can't find a solution for multiples couples of variables like these:

```
$scope.date1startFrom;
$scope.date1startTo;
$scope.date2startFrom;
$scope.date2startTo;
$scope.date3startFrom;
$scope.date3startTo;
```

I have to see the alert only if very element of the couple has a value. I find this solution but I want to extend it to multiple values but I can't.

```
var datesAreDefined =  $scope.date1startFrom && $scope.date1startTo;
if (datesAreDefined && !periodFromAndToIsValid($scope.date1startFrom,  $scope.date1startTo)) {
    alert("error");
}

function periodFromAndToIsValid (from, to){
    var fromDate = new Date(from).getTime();
    var toDate = new Date(to).getTime();
    return toDate >= fromDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend to use something like MomentJS its very effective for this case:

https://momentjs.com/

In this link you can find the way to make comparisons easily between dates.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/